# React Redux - Reducer with CRUD - best practices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I wrote simple reducer for `User` entity, and now I want to apply best practices for it, when switching action types and returning state. Just to mention, I extracted actions types in separate file, `actionsTypes.js`.

Content of `actionsTypes.js` :

```
export const GET_USERS_SUCCESS = 'GET_USERS_SUCCESS';
export const GET_USER_SUCCESS = 'GET_USER_SUCCESS';
export const ADD_USER_SUCCESS = 'ADD_USER_SUCCESS';
export const EDIT_USER_SUCCESS = 'EDIT_USER_SUCCESS';
export const DELETE_USER_SUCCESS = 'DELETE_USER_SUCCESS';
```

First question, is it mandatory to have actions types for `FAILED` case? For example, to add `GET_USERS_FAILED` and so on and handle them inside usersReducer?

Root reducer is:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    users
});
```

There is code of usersReducer, and I put comments/questions inside code, and ask for answers (what are best practices to handle action types):

```
export default function usersReducer(state = initialState.users, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionsTypes.GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
        // state of usersReducer is 'users' array, so I just return action.payload where it is array of users. Will it automatically update users array on initial state?
            return action.payload;
        case actionsTypes.GET_USER_SUCCESS:
        // What to return here? Just action.payload where it is just single user object? 
            return ;
        case actionsTypes.ADD_USER_SUCCESS:
        // what does this mean? Can someone explain this code? It returns new array, but what about spread operator, and object.assign?
            return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload.id),
                Object.assign({}, action.payload)];
        case actionsTypes.EDIT_USER_SUCCESS:
        // is this ok?
            const indexOfUser = state.findIndex(user => user.id === action.payload.id);
            let newState = [...state];
            newState[indexOfUser] = action.payload;
            return newState;
        case actionsTypes.DELETE_USER_SUCCESS:
        // I'm not sure about this delete part, is this ok or there is best practice to return state without deleted user?
            return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.user.id)];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same question.I've just seen this was posted 2 years ago.If you've got some best practices , i'll be glad if you can share.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an experienced developer but let me answer your questions what I've learned and encountered up to now.

> First question, is it mandatory to have actions types for FAILED case?
>   For example, to add GET_USERS_FAILED and so on and handle them inside
>   usersReducer?

This is not mandatory but if you intend to give a feedback to your clients it would be good. For example, you initiated the `GET_USERS` process and it failed somehow. Nothing happens on client side, nothing updated etc. So, your client does not know it failed and wonders why nothing happened. But, if you have a failure case and you catch the error, you can inform your client that there was an error.

To do this, you can consume `GET_USERS_FAILED` action type in two pleases for example. One in your `userReducers` and one for, lets say, an `error` or `feedback` reducer. First one returns state since your process failed and you can't get the desired data, hence does not want to mutate the state anyhow. Second one updates your feedback reducer and can change a state, lets say `error` and you catch this state in your component and if `error` state is true you show a nice message to your client.

> state of usersReducer is 'users' array, so I just return
>   action.payload where it is array of users. Will it automatically
>   update users array on initial state?

```
case actionsTypes.GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
    return action.payload;
```

This is ok if you are fetching whole users with a single request. This means your action.payload which is an array becomes your state. But, if you don't want to fetch all the users with a single request, like pagination, this would be not enough. You need to concat your state with the fetched ones.

```
case actionsTypes.GET_USERS_SUCCESS:
    return [...state, ...action.payload];
```

Here, we are using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

It, obviously, spread what is given to it :) You can use it in a multiple ways for arrays and also objects. You can check the documentation. But here is some simple examples.

```
const arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
const newArr = [ ...arr, 4 ];
// newArr is now [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

We spread `arr` in a new array and add 4 to it.

```
const obj = { id: 1, name: "foo, age: 25 };
const newObj = { ...obj, age: 30 };
// newObj is now { id: 1, name: "foo", age: 30 }
```

Here, we spread our `obj` in a new object and changed its age property. In both examples, we never mutate our original data.

> What to return here? Just action.payload where it is just single user
>   object?

```
case actionsTypes.GET_USER_SUCCESS:
    return ;
```

Probably you can't use this action in this reducer directly. Because your state here holds your users as an array. What do you want to do the user you got somehow? Lets say you want to hold a "selected" user. Either you can create a separate reducer for that or change your state here, make it an object and hold a `selectedUser` property and update it with this. But if you change your state's shape, all the other reducer parts need to be changed since your state will be something like this:

```
{
    users: [],
    selectedUser,
}
```

Now, your state is not an array anymore, it is an object. All your code must be changed according to that.

> what does this mean? Can someone explain this code? It returns new
>   array, but what about spread operator, and object.assign?

```
case actionsTypes.ADD_USER_SUCCESS:
    return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload.id), Object.assign({}, action.payload)];
```

I've already tried to explain spread syntax. [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) copies some values to a target or updates it or merges two of them. What does this code do?

First it takes your state, filters it and returns the users not equal to your action.payload one, which is the user is being added. This returns an array, so it spreads it and merges it with the Object.assign part. In Object.assign part it takes an empty object and merges it with the user. An all those values creates a new array which is your new state. Let's say your state is like:

```
[
    { id: 1, name: "foo" },
    { id: 2, name: "bar" },
]
```

and your new user is:

```
{
     id: 3, name: "baz"
}
```

Here what this code does. First it filters all the user and since filter criteria does not match it returns all your users (state) then spread it (don't forget, filter returns an array and we spread this array into another one):

```
[ { id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" } ]
```

Now the Object.assign part does its job and merges an empty object with action.payload, a user object. Now our final array will be like this:

```
[ { id: 1, name: "foo"}, { id: 2, name: "bar" }, { id: 3, name: "baz" } ]
```

But, actually Object.assign is not needed here. Why do we bother merging our object with an empty one again? So, this code does the same job:

```
case actionsTypes.ADD_USER_SUCCESS:
    return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.payload.id), action.payload ];
```

> is this ok?

```
case actionsTypes.EDIT_USER_SUCCESS:
    const indexOfUser = state.findIndex(user => user.id === action.payload.id);
    let newState = [...state];
    newState[indexOfUser] = action.payload;
    return newState;
```

It seems ok to me. You don't mutate the state directly, use spread syntax to create a new one, update the related part and finally set your state with this new one.

> I'm not sure about this delete part, is this ok or there is best
>   practice to return state without deleted user?

```
case actionsTypes.DELETE_USER_SUCCESS:
    return [...state.filter(user => user.id !== action.user.id)];
```

Again, it seems ok to me. You filter the deleted user and update your state according to that. Of course there are other situations you should take into considiration . For example do you have a backend process for those? Do you add or delete users to a database? If yes for all the parts you need to sure about the backend process success and after that you need to update your state. But this is a different topic I guess.